# Download url content using file-get-contents

Tags: php, file-get-contents

I am trying to get content from my client's website and upload it to my website after some processing.

I am trying to use file_get_contents to obtain the content in PHP environment.

If I use:

```
file_get_contents("http://www.maideden.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=59&product_id=96")
```

I am able to get all the content.

However, if I use a variable to store the address like

```
$url = "http://www.maideden.com/index.php?route=product/product&path=59&product_id=96"
```

and use `file_get_contents($url);` it did not return anything.

Can anyone help me on this? I will prefer to use `file_get_contents($url)`

Comment: There is no reason at all that those two examples should behave any differently. It's likely you've missed a semi-colon somewhere (like at the end of your second example) and that's what is causing an error. Have you tried `var_dump(file_get_contents($url))` to see what it returns?

Comment: how about **readfile($url)**

Comment: It's possible that the configurations differ? It seems that allow_url_fopen needs to be true to allow that to work (http://php.net/manual/en/filesystem.configuration.php#ini.allow-url-fopen). As an alternative, look into the curl* functions?

Comment: you might have errors turned off as far as I can see there is a missing `;` after `$url=...`

Comment: "did not return anything." what is the http status code? is that 500?